# How to center float list elements inside an unordered list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this css that puts icons as list items and puts them in an unordered list, I want to be able to center the list items when I change the screen size.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 120px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
li{
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

currently my code looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/x2SR6/

Currently there is a lot of blank space on the right side when i change the screen size how can I fix this

Comment: I would suggest that you might try using [css media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and adjusting the width of the ul at certain break point sizes for screens, rather than trying to support it for any resolution, especially if you later can't continue to use font awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is use `text-align:center` on the `ul` and and `display:inline-block` on the li.  This will get you started, you also need `height:auto` on the ul.

Here's the css from an updated fiddle.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-right: 120px;
    text-align:center;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You also need to wrap the ul so that the arrows appear at the top, that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This is great thank you! Why do I need height:auto; exactly though? I only want one row to be visible at a time.

Comment: If you only want the first row visible then omit the height:auto. Also if you like the answer, please up-vote it.  If it solves your problem don't forget to use the checkmark to flag it as accepted.  These things help the answerer, but also help your reputation.